# The best way to display multiple user emails in the dashboard?

Tags: email, dashboard

Story:

As a user I can add several emails to my account.
As a manager I want to be able to display all emails assigned to the account

I am looking for an idea how to display this assignment (I only have 300px width).

One email is key, the rest can be hidden. I have some ideas but maybe someone has better ones ;)

Comment: Please describe your exact problem and share the ideas you already have with an explanation why they don't work. The question is too broad to get answers this site aims for.

Answer (score 0):

If the user needs to read the full lengths of the email you only have 3 choices:

- wrap the text
- disclose the value or
- redesign the element to accommodate more space

In the disclosure option, it's possible to limit the number of chars. displayed for each email address and apply an ellipses. When the user needs to read the full email address, they can focus or hover on the object, and the system can display a tool-tip for the full string value.